# PropertyGrid do action after Editing with the help of UITypeEditor or TypeConverter to change an other property

Tags: c#, .net, properties, propertygrid

I have a class with some properties. After changing one of them I want to react and change an other propertie. This action should done by an UITypeEditor or the TypeConverter and not by an event in the class itself.

I don't want to use INotifyPropertyChanged and handle this in the class itself.

not tested sample code

```
public class MyEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        // change the other property
    }
}

[Editor(typeof(MyEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
class MyClass
{
    public string String1 { get; set; } 
    public string String2 { get; set; } 
    public string String3 { get; set; } 
}
```

This EditValue has only a function in showing the editor modal with a little button ... But I want to have a normal textbox with an AfterChange or so.

Comment: UITypeEditors in the property grid only support modal or dropdown form, you can't have some kind of inplace TextBox replacing the grid entry value. Please elaborate what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [NotifyParentPropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.notifyparentpropertyattribute%28v=vs.90%29) on MSDN.
The referenced sample shows how a change of a property in the class BorderAppearance triggers the BorderAppearanceConverter.
In your case you would need a MyClassConverter that reacts on the event and add the NotifyParentPropertyAttribute to each of your three properties.